# How to get friends profile picture from gmail contacts?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to import GMail contacts (friends list). I have got friends' mail id, name, and phone number, but if I tried to get the images it says "401 error".

The code I have used is as follows:

```
GDataLink *photoLink = [contact photoLink];
NSLog(@"%@",photoLink);

NSURL *imageURL = [photoLink URL];
NSLog(@"image url = %@",imageURL);
```

How can I get friends' profile picture? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: what does a typical photoLink URL look like to you, when it's logged in your console?

Comment: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/username%40gmail.com/63402b0d25e6ad    I got a link just like above

Comment: So is there any other way to get the photolink URL?

Comment: Hi Could you please let me know how you got the the contact details. If possible could you please share the code

Answer (score 1):

[Looking at some other (public) code that's roughly the same as what you're doing](https://github.com/nparry/gdata-objectivec-client/blob/master/Examples/ContactsSample/ContactsSampleWindowController.m), I see that you should be using an ***auth token*** with these photo links.  Without that auth token, Google assumes you might be malicious and will send back a 401 error.

E.G.

```
    GDataLink *photoLink = [contact photoLink];

    NSString *imageETag = [photoLink ETag];
    if (imageETag == nil || ![mContactImageETag isEqual:imageETag]) {

      if (imageETag != nil) {

        // get an NSURLRequest object with an auth token
        NSURL *imageURL = [photoLink URL];
        GDataServiceGoogleContact *service = [self contactService];

        // requestForURL:ETag:httpMethod: sets the user agent header of the
        // request and, when using ClientLogin, adds the authorization header
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [service requestForURL:imageURL
                                                         ETag:nil
                                                   httpMethod:nil];

        [request setValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
        [fetcher setAuthorizer:[service authorizer]];
        [fetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
                 didFinishSelector:@selector(imageFetcher:finishedWithData:error:)];
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi its getting crash while calling the method '@selector(imageFetcher:finishedWithData:error:)'

Fetcher method is
'- (GDataServiceGoogleContact *)contactService {
    static GDataServiceGoogleContact* service = nil;
    if (!service) {
        service = [[GDataServiceGoogleContact alloc] init];
        [service setShouldCacheResponseData:YES];
        [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
        [service setAuthorizer:@"My Access Token"];
    }
    return service;
}'